# using Request npm module synchronous in Meteor 1.3

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, npm, npm-request

I try to use [request npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) in Meteor 1.3.2.4 as synchronous.

Based on [this Meteor guide article](http://guide.meteor.com/using-npm-packages.html#async-callbacks), first I try to use `Meteor.bindEnvironment` like below:

```
    import request from 'request';

    let result = {success: false, error: null, content: ""};
    let requestOptions = {
        url: <MY-URL-HERE>
    };

    request(requestOptions, Meteor.bindEnvironment((error, response, html) => {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            result.success = true;
            result.content = html;
            result.error = null;
        }
        else {
            result.success = false;
            result.content = "";
            result.error = error;
        }
    }));
```

But it seems still async call.

In next step I try to use `Meteor.wrapAsync` based on [this answer](https://forums.meteor.com/t/npm-request-vs-atmosphere-http/23285/4?u=cyclops) on meteor forum, this is next try code:

```
        import request from 'request';

        let result = {success: false, error: null, content: ""};
        let requestOptions = {
            url: <MY-URL-HERE>
        };

        let func = function (options, callback) {
            request(options, function (error, response, body) {
                console.log("error: " + JSON.stringify(error));
                console.log("response: " + JSON.stringify(response));
                console.log("body: " + JSON.stringify(body));
                callback(error, {response, body});
            });
        };

        let {error, response, body} = syncRequest(requestOptions);

         console.log("error2: " + JSON.stringify(error));
         console.log("response2: " + JSON.stringify(response));
         console.log("body2: " + JSON.stringify(body));

        if (response.statusCode == 200) {
            result.success = true;
            result.content = body;
            result.error = null;
        }
        else {
            result.success = false;
            result.content = "";
            result.error = error;
        }
```

This code works fine except request contain error. When request contain error (for example url is incorrect) this break with below exception:

```
I20160518-08:24:22.180(4.5)? error: {}
I20160518-08:24:22.181(4.5)? response: undefined
I20160518-08:24:22.182(4.5)? body: undefined
W20160518-08:24:22.839(4.5)? (STDERR) TypeError: The header content contains invalid characters
W20160518-08:24:22.839(4.5)? (STDERR)     at Object.Future.wait (/home/cyc/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.3.2_4.7bk6xv++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:420:15)
W20160518-08:24:22.839(4.5)? (STDERR)     at packages/meteor/helpers.js:119:1
W20160518-08:24:22.839(4.5)? (STDERR)     at Object.getContent (server/lib/get_content.js:51:26)
W20160518-08:24:22.839(4.5)? (STDERR)     at Object.fetch (server/lib/get_content.js:205:27)
W20160518-08:24:22.839(4.5)? (STDERR)     at Object.fetchSource (server/lib/get_content.js:369:31)
W20160518-08:24:22.840(4.5)? (STDERR)     at [object Object].action (server/controller/postsController.js:79:39)
W20160518-08:24:22.840(4.5)? (STDERR)     at [object Object].handle (packages/iron_middleware-stack/lib/handler.js:74:1)
W20160518-08:24:22.840(4.5)? (STDERR)     at boundNext (packages/iron_middleware-stack/lib/middleware_stack.js:251:1)
W20160518-08:24:22.840(4.5)? (STDERR)     at runWithEnvironment (packages/meteor/dynamics_nodejs.js:110:1)
W20160518-08:24:22.840(4.5)? (STDERR)     at packages/meteor/dynamics_nodejs.js:123:1
W20160518-08:24:22.840(4.5)? (STDERR)     - - - - -
W20160518-08:24:22.840(4.5)? (STDERR)     at ClientRequest.OutgoingMessage.setHeader (http.js:733:13)
W20160518-08:24:22.840(4.5)? (STDERR)     at new ClientRequest (http.js:1429:14)
W20160518-08:24:22.840(4.5)? (STDERR)     at Object.exports.request (http.js:1899:10)
W20160518-08:24:22.841(4.5)? (STDERR)     at Request.start (/home/cyc/Programming/Projects/content/Sources/node_modules/request/request.js:753:32)
W20160518-08:24:22.841(4.5)? (STDERR)     at Request.end (/home/cyc/Programming/Projects/content/Sources/node_modules/request/request.js:1418:10)
W20160518-08:24:22.841(4.5)? (STDERR)     at end (/home/cyc/Programming/Projects/content/Sources/node_modules/request/request.js:580:14)
W20160518-08:24:22.841(4.5)? (STDERR)     at Object._onImmediate (/home/cyc/Programming/Projects/content/Sources/node_modules/request/request.js:594:7)
W20160518-08:24:22.841(4.5)? (STDERR)     at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:363:15)
```

Now I have two question:

1. How to fix above code?
2. Is this approach is the best way to use request npm module synchronous in Meteor or you know better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### binding the environment

`Meteor.bindEnvironment` simply makes sure that your callback is called in the context you were using when calling the original function. It does not supposed to make your code appear synchronous. If you did not use it, your callback will not be run inside a fiber (which will prevent you from performing some actions) and you won't have access to certain variables (such as the current user). There is an [excellent video](https://www.eventedmind.com/items/meteor-what-is-meteor-bindenvironment) by Crhis Mather on the subject (keep in mind that some of the code is a bit outdated, but the core is still valid).

### wrapping an async function

`Meteor.wrapAsync` wraps functions that expect a callback with the standard error-first 2 arguments signature. Since the `request` does not adhere to this exact standard (it uses a callback with 3 arguments), the forum post suggested wrapping it with a function that expects a callback with the aforementioned 2 arguments.

The convention is that the result of calling a "wrapped" function is the value of the second argument passed to the callback (the `data`), and an error is thrown if there is one.

Therefore, as it is now, you can wrap the function with a `try..catch` block and see if there is an error.

Another option is to never raise an error:

```
let func = function (options, callback) {
  request(options, function (error, response, body) {
    callback(null, {response, body, error});
  });
};
```

Which will always result in a `{response, body, error}` object, where `error` will be `null` if there is no error.

### using the http package

I think that the [http](http://docs.meteor.com/api/http.html#HTTP-call) package is perfectly valid and does pretty much the same for you with convenience methods (e.g, the general `call`, and specific `get` and `post`):

For example:

```
import { HTTP } from 'meteor/http';
const result = HTTP.get('https://my-url.com');
```

Comment: Thanks for your complete and awesome answer. But I have one question about http package approach. Is this package still maintain and useful for future works? Many people said me to prevent using this and use request npm package for this. When it's better to use http package?? (your third approach)

Comment: It is difficult to predict the future, but at the moment the http package is maintained by the MDG and is quite a highly used one. Even if the implementation will change at some point, it is likely to keep its interface. That said, Meteor may eventually retire Atmosphere in favor of NPM, and when it does, devs will need to migrate their apps anyway, so `http` will probably not be your biggest concern. I would ask for references of MDG plans to deprecate it or other explanation for those claims.